# How to drop a partition via Synonym

Tags: oracle

I have a table with partitions, and would like to drop partition via a synonym pointing to that table. How come I get the following error:

> Table of view does not exists

Here is my query:

```
Alter table call_logs drop partition <partition_name>;
```

But when I run:

```
select count(*) from call_logs;
```

I get 256781?

The synonym belongs to one user while the table call_logs belong to another user.
The name of the table and the name of the synonym are identical
I m using Oracle 12c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to synonyms in the following DML statements: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, FLASHBACK TABLE, EXPLAIN PLAN, and LOCK TABLE. You can refer to synonyms in the following DDL statements: AUDIT, NOAUDIT, GRANT, REVOKE, and COMMENT.

Therefore, you cannot use a synonym to make an alter table when your are using the synonym name to reference the table.

Regards